# How can memset be called with memcpy as the first argument if memcpy doesn't actually return anything?

Tags: c, glibc

I'm attempting to port some libc code to Rust. Specifically, the __tcgetattr() function [found in this file](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/tcgetattr.c.html#80).

There is only one section that I'm having a problem with.

```
if (sizeof (cc_t) == 1 || _POSIX_VDISABLE == 0
    || (unsigned char) _POSIX_VDISABLE == (unsigned char) -1)
  memset (__mempcpy (&termios_p->c_cc[0], &k_termios.c_cc[0],
                     __KERNEL_NCCS * sizeof (cc_t)),
          _POSIX_VDISABLE, (NCCS - __KERNEL_NCCS) * sizeof (cc_t));
else
  {
    memcpy (&termios_p->c_cc[0], &k_termios.c_cc[0],
            __KERNEL_NCCS * sizeof (cc_t));

    for (size_t cnt = __KERNEL_NCCS; cnt < NCCS; ++cnt)
      termios_p->c_cc[cnt] = _POSIX_VDISABLE;
  }
```

I'm confused by what memset is doing in the first logic statement.

```
      memset (__mempcpy (&termios_p->c_cc[0], &k_termios.c_cc[0],
                     __KERNEL_NCCS * sizeof (cc_t)),
          _POSIX_VDISABLE, (NCCS - __KERNEL_NCCS) * sizeof (cc_t));
```

From what I remember, memcpy doesn't actually return anything. It updates the value passed as the first parameter. I can't find any information on __memcpy, but I'm assuming it's similar. If so, why is memcpy being passed as a parameter when it doesn't have a return value?

Comment: From the Fine Manual: `The  mempcpy()  function  is  nearly  identical  to the memcpy(3) function.  It copies n bytes from the object beginning at src into the object pointed to by dest.  But instead of
       returning the value of dest it returns a pointer to the byte following the last written byte.`

Comment: Why the down votes?

Comment: Probably because your question can be answered by a simple RTFM? BTW: the [str|mem][lp]xxx() stem from BSD and are/were intended to actually use these useful return values. (but maybe you were confused by the double leading underscore?)

Comment: `man mempcpy` did it for me. For help on man: `man man`

Comment: I guess my C skills are not on par. I thought a function declared with a void type didn't return anything

Comment: Yeah I was overlooking the fact that it's a void pointer.

Comment: @mattmc you are also missing the point that `__mempcpy` != `__memcpy`.

Comment: Thanks @shepmaster. Once again you post with a one liner and don't contribute any information.

Comment: @mattmc I'm open to some feedback on how I could have better pointed out that `mem` **p** `cpy` is a different function than `memcpy`. Your code is `memset (__mempcpy`, but you state "memcpy doesn't actually return anything".

Comment: Note: the pointer being `void*` is completely irrelevant here.

Comment: You are right @shepmaster. Sorry. Just getting mad at all the down votes. That's exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not an exact answer to your question, but, there is `libc` crate at [crates.io](https://crates.io/crates/libc). I searched in the documnetation for `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` and it seems the `tcgetattr()` function is already [implemented](https://doc.rust-lang.org/libc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libc/fn.tcgetattr.html). On that page you can also click on [src] and see how it has been implemented.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm familiar with the libc crate, but I figured I would try to actually port a bit of C code to Rust instead of using C bindings. It was going well until this part.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18248206)

Comment: @RyanK I don't see what essential part should have been included. Copy all the type definitions and extern declarations? Sounds like a bad idea to me.